# Sharp jump in memory consumption only in the Opera browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, opera

## Update

It looks like a bug. Disabled the extension. When click on the site, there is an increase in memory, but not much. If just open the dev console and click again - a sharp jump.

## Old post

We have an chrome extension with the next function. Its task is wait to shown a key element and run callback.

```
function waitPageToComplete(key, callback) {
    let timerId = setInterval(function () {
        if (document.querySelector(key)) {
            clearInterval(timerId);
            callback(key);
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

The function is called when the `complete` event occurs.

```
// backgroud.js
function onTabsUpdated(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { message: 'complete' });
    }
}

// content-script.js
function onBackgroundMessage(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message == 'complete') {
        waitPageToComplete(someKey, someCallback);
    }
}
```

### Opera browser

1. Put a breakpoint on any line of the function `waitPageToComplete`:
2. Refresh page. Catch breakpoint and click continue. Memory consumption is `~100mb` (task manager opera)
3. Go to another page on the same site.
4. Catch breakpoint. Memory up to `1,5gb`.

What's happen? If there is no breakpoint, this also happens. But not every time. With the breakpoint constantly.

### Chrome browser

No such problem. Not by random, not with a breakpoint. The same code, the same extension.

- Windows 7, x64
- Chrome 81.0.4044.138, x64
- Opera 68.0.3618.63, x64

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the browser so I guess you should report it to their bug tracker or forum. Does this happen if you don't open devtools? Try using MutationObserver instead of setInterval.

Comment: @wOxxOm It looks like this is really a bug. Disabled the extension. When click on the site, there is an increase in memory, but not much. If just open the dev console and click again - a sharp jump.